# How can I find information about CSS browser incompatibilities?

Tags: css, cross-browser

Many times when I read books related to CSS I see things like this "this will not work on some browser", "this hack will work for that browser".

Where I can all information that I need to know the hacks for working for all browsers?

thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I suggest [Quirksmode](http://www.quirksmode.org/). Very useful resource for web development.

Here is a link for the CSS page on Quirksmode:

http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html

Comment: Agreed, Quirksmode is the best resource for CSS and JavaScript browser compatibility information.

Answer (score 1):

I've found the [SitePoint CSS reference](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css) very helpful.

Comment: Agreed, SitePoint is great stuff

Answer (score 0):

You could start with:

[CSS contents and browser compatibility](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html)

And if you're interested in e-mail clients as well as browsers:

[Guide to CSS support in email clients (2008)](http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/)

Answer (score 0):

I always found [this particular comparison](http://www.webdevout.net/browser-support#css) useful, as it shows whether or not a particular feature is supported, and how well they are supported. It may prove useful for you as well.

> This document will summarize the level of support for web standards and maturing technologies in popular web browsers. It covers the Internet Explorer, Firefox, and Opera web browsers, with focus on the HTML, CSS, DOM, and ECMAScript technologies.

Other than that, [Quirksmode](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html) is a great resource.

Answer (score 0):

[Position Is Everyting](http://www.positioniseverything.net/) can be useful for finding solutions to problems (mostly related to IE6 and below). They don't have a browser comparison and they have names for bugs that may not always be intuitive, so it's not always easy to find specific incompatibilities.

The articles go into a lot of detail and usually have several possible fixes, so once you've found a rendering bug, it can be quite useful. I wouldn't recommend using all their fixes directly, since they often involve browser-specific CSS hacks. It's usually better to use conditional comments.